# creating a fuzzer for ftp

Tags: python, ftp, kali-linux

I keep getting the error when I try to connect to the ftp server:

> a bytes like object is required not str

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
buffer = "\x41" * 1000
s.connect(('192.168.43.129',2222))
data = s.recv(1024)
print ("Sending data to WarFTP...")
s.send('USER '+buffer+'\r\n')
data = s.recv(1024)

s.send(' PASS PASSWORD '+'\r\n')
s.close()
print ("Finish")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your string with `.encode()`.

```
buffer = "\x41" * 1000
data_to_send = 'USER ' + buffer + '\r\n'
data_to_send.encode()
s.send(data_to_send)
```

Some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) you may find useful